# asp net mvc cross site layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have two ASP NET sites. They has different logic and pages, getting/writing data from different databases.
I want to create a **Master** layout (with header, menu footer ect) and join this sites like they are looks like one single site. So the question is is it possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve something like displaying different models in one view? If yes, then you can use `ViewModels`. Create `viewModel` class and in here include what models do you want to display.

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public Book Book  { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        //and so on...
    }
```

Then in your action method you need to create new viewModel and pass it to the return view.

```
    var viewModel = new ViewModel
                {
                    Books= db.Books.ToList(),
                    Genres = db.Genres.ToList()
//you can also of course specify here a Book or Genre 
                };

return View(viewModel);
```

In your view/or layout specify the model what you are using.

```
@model YourProjectName.ViewModels.ViewModel
```

And now you have access to all properties what you have specified in `viewModel` class.

More about View Models:

[Way to Use Multiple Models in a view in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/way-to-use-multiple-models-in-a-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

[What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)